# Editing navigation bar of singapore theme in beamer

Tags: beamer, headline

I like the singapore theme used in beamer. the only things that i want to edit is the presentation of navigation bar.

Here a picture and the minimal code of the existing navigation bar with three sections.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[compress]{Singapore}
\begin{document}
\section{section 1}
\begin{frame}
     test
\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\begin{frame}
     test
\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\begin{frame}
    test
\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\begin{frame}
       test
\end{frame}

\section{section 2}
\begin{frame}
    test
\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\begin{frame}
     test
\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\begin{frame}
     test
\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\begin{frame}
     test
\end{frame}

\section{section 3}
\begin{frame}
   test
\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\begin{frame}
    test
\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\begin{frame}
    test
\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\begin{frame} 
   test
\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\begin{frame}
    test
\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\begin{frame}
    test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I want to costumize the navigation bar as the next illustration.

[image]

Thanks you for your help.